# How to fit the piecewise function and make the piecewise point continuous and the first derivative of the piecewise function equal?

Tags: python, spline, piecewise

When I want to use a piecewise function to fit my data, I don't know how to realize that the fitted function is continuous at the breakpoint and its first derivative is equal, that is, to smooth the piecewise function.

I tried to fit the data separately, but as shown in the figure, I didn't know how to add constraints to the fitting process.

[image]

```
def func(x, a0, a1,a2):
    return a0+(a1/x)+a2/(x*x)
def highfunc(x1,b0,b1,b2):
    return b0+b1*x1+b2*x1*x1
x=speed_low
y=ddma_low
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
a0=popt[0]
a1=popt[1]
a2=popt[2]
yvals = func(x,a0,a1,a2) #拟合y值
x1=speed_high
y1=ddma_high
popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(highfunc, x1, y1)
b0=popt1[0]
b1=popt1[1]
b2=popt1[2]
yvals1 = highfunc(x1,b0,b1,b2) #拟合y值
xxxxx=np.hstack((x,x1))
yyyyy=np.hstack((yvals,yvals1))
#########################画图####################################
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
levels=np.linspace(0,3,7)
gci=ax.hist2d(Good_ddma,speed_cygnss,bins=400,cmap="jet",norm=LogNorm())
plot2 = plt.scatter(yvals,x,s=0.8,c='k',label='polyfit values')
plot3 = plt.scatter(yvals1,x1,s=0.8,c='r',label='polyfit values')
plot4 = plt.scatter(eeeeeefffff,windspeed_queue,s=20,c='k',marker='+')
```

The two lines I want to fit are smooth and continuous, that is, the first`enter code here` derivative of breakpoint is equal, but after a long time thinking, the spline fitting function can not work, because my piecewise function has limited the expression, this problem has troubled me for many days.

Comment: I am a beginning student. I hope someone can point out my problems or tell me how to add constraints to the piecewise fitting function. Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are asking for is what spline fitting is - piecewise functions whose derivatives are also equal at the endpoints. If you can specify the location of the knots that will be exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't know how to have the function expression under the condition of using spline function fitting, in python interpolate the BSpline (t, c, k, extrapolate = False) only allow me to enter the X, Y array, and then return the fitting results, I'd like to know how I can get my function fitting expressions of the above section

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you for your reply.